# How to generate WADL for Spring REST Service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-3

Hi I am working with Spring 3.5.0.Release. I want to generate a WADL for my spring rest service. Is their any functionality in Spring by which i can easily generate the WADL.

Comment: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/02/automatically-generating-wadl-in-spring.html#!/2012/02/automatically-generating-wadl-in-spring.html

Comment: This tutorial is not proper and systematic , i didn't get anything form this.  Can you please elaborate more or share some sample

Answer (score 2):

You can use Swagger-SpringMVC, which will automatically integrate Swagger compliant API-docs into your application.

Version 1.0.2 is stable and supports Swagger 1.2.

Version 2.0.0 is currently under development and will support Swagger 2.0.

The api-docs will be accessible using
http://localhost:8080/api-docs 
then.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox

You can also use Swagger-UI to access the API-docs and you can generate the client code using Swagger-Codegen.

Comment: This is useful indeed, for swagger. But the question was about integrating WADL.