# Error to submit a form using Spring MVC - HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying make a simple form and submit it using Spring MVC. I tried several ways to make it, all pages are mapped on `web.xml` and I check it navigate using simple pages. But when the button is clicked I receive the follow error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not found
Type Status Report

Message /addEmployee

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.20
```

**employeeHome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cadastro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cadastro</h1>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name"/></td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="id">ID</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="id"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="contactNumber">Contact Number</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="contactNumber"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller: **SpringMVCHelloWorld**

```
@Controller
public class SpringMVCHelloWorld {

    // Employee
    @GetMapping("/employeeHome")
    public ModelAndView showForm() {
        return new ModelAndView("employeeHome", "employee", new Employee());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "error";
        }   
        model.addAttribute("name",employee.getName());
        model.addAttribute("contactNumber",employee.getContactNumber());
        model.addAttribute("id", employee.getId());     
        return "employeeView";
    }

}
```

I think that the problem is to set the `action` on .jsp page and on `@RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)` method, but I don't know what is wrong.

**EDIT: Problem solved**

Change

```
<form:form method="post" action="/addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">
```

to

```
<form:form method="post" action="addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">
```

Comment: try this <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="employee"> instead of <form:form method="POST" action="/addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">

Comment: If I do it, how I mapping the form submit on controller?

Comment: Try it once and let spring form do the magic for you.

Comment: @AjayKumar The Spring's magic is: `Request method 'POST' not supported`

Comment: You are in right direction now. Now, take a look at it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699350/spring-request-method-post-not-supported and this too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498223/spring-boot-request-method-post-not-supported-tried-everything?rq=1

Comment: Don't works for me.

Comment: Refert this and see what you are missing - https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks

Comment: @AjayKumar I solved the problem change it: `<form:form method="post" action="/addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">` to `<form:form method="post" action="addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">`. Yes, just removing `/`

Comment: Great. I am glad its working for you now.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue might be with action `URL`

You can try like this

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">
```

or hardcode baseUrl if any like this

```
<form:form method="POST" action="baseContextPath/addEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">
```

You can [refer this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial) for more detail and [working code here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-mvc-forms-jsp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/employeeHome.jsp)

Comment: I followed these refers. I tried the two solutions, but the problem persist. What means ${pageContext.request.contextPath} ? I can't see this variable on the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850336/what-does-this-expression-language-pagecontext-request-contextpath-exactly-do